# react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

> react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next

I recently added the package and got this error. I have followed all the steps as far as I know.

I use Next.js with the `next-i18next` package which usually initialises itself automatically.

https://github.com/m2vi/downloader

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [`next-i18next` docs](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next#how-does-it-work):

> Then we add `serverSideTranslation` to `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` (depending on your case) in our page-level components.

Meaning you'll need to add [`serverSideTranslation`](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next#serversidetranslations) to the pages that need translations.

---

For example in your `pages/d/[tab]/index` file:

```js
import Head from 'next/head';
import { Input } from '../../../components/Input';
import YouTube from '../../../components/youtube/Main';
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';

const index = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>YouTube</title>
            </Head>
            <YouTube />
        </>
    );
};

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ locale }) => ({
    props: {
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common']))
    }
});

export default index;
```

Then further down in your `Main` component you can access the `documentation` translation using:

```js
t('pages.documentation')
```

Comment: This didn't work for me until I added `react: { useSuspense: false }` to my `next-i18next-config.js` file.

Comment: how about the case when using getStaticProps in dynamic pages

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing Same applies to `getStaticProps`.

Comment: well on dynamic pages. when we use `getStaticProps`, we need to pass getStaticPaths as well, what would be thrown inside `getStaticPaths` in this case ?

Comment: Nothing needs to change in `getStaticPaths`, that's only used to define what paths needs to be generated at build time.

Comment: There's also a nice blog post here: https://locize.com/blog/next-i18next/

Comment: `serverSideTranslations` isn't there anymore and not mentioned in the starting up guide...

Answer (score 22):

In my case the problem was a silly typo caused by the VSC import suggestions and at first place my carelessness.

So instead of:

```js
import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
```

... the import statement was:

```js
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
```

Comment: thankyou worked for me

Answer (score 9):

## update next-i18next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        locales: ['en', 'de', 'fr'],
    },
    react: { useSuspense: false },//this line
};
```

Comment: Be aware that all the strings ids will appear (like "common/something"), till the translations is loaded if you turned this off. This is more noticable in case the translations are coming from the backend.

Comment: This did not work

Comment: not work for me either. this is happening to me only on nextjs dynamic page `/[id]/edit`

Comment: It is not working for me either.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
in your next-i18next.config.js:

```
    const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        defaultLocale: 'fr',
        locales: ['en', 'fr'],
        localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales')
    },
};
```

and in your _app.js try to pass the config file as a sencond param like this :

```
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next'
import nextI18NextConfig from '../../next-i18next.config'
....
export default appWithTranslation(MyApp, nextI18NextConfig);
```

N.B if you are using Next.js's dynamic import feature to load a module only on the client side disable it otherwise it will not work

```
export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(index), { ssr: false }); //to be removed
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to import the i18n into the root of your app. This will resolve the error message and allow the translations to work properly.

This is outlined in the docs:
[https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks#:~:text=Then%20import%20that%20in%20index.js%3A](https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks#:%7E:text=Then%20import%20that%20in%20index.js%3A)

P.S. If clicking the link doesn't bring you to the exact location, search in the document (ctr + f): "Then import that in index.js"

Answer (score 0):

This error message may be shown although it is not the root cause of the problem.

I had the following build error message:

```
react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at LanguageSwitcherLink ...
```

The root cause here was the TypeError.

In my case, the TypeError occurred because I had components with parameters in `pages` directory. Thus, during `next build` these components were attempted to be build as static pages. This failed because expected parameters were missing, which is why they were undefined.

Solution for me: move components outside of `pages` folder.
Afterwards, there is also no error message anymore with respect to `initReactI18next`.

Comment: My components are not in pages folder but I get these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, problem was that I wasn't importing the i18n.js file in app.js. Check and make sure you are importing this file correctly in your app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you face this error in react and jest, maybe this one can help you:

```
    jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
    // this mock makes sure any components using the translate hook can use it without a warning being shown
    useTranslation: () => {
        return {
            t: (str: string) => str,
            i18n: {
                changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {}),
            },
        }
    },
    initReactI18next: {
        type: '3rdParty',
        init: () => {},
    },
}))
```

as suggested in [official doc](https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing).

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue too.

But I had "revalidate" property in getStaticProps. When I removed it, the error went away.

P.S. Maybe this will help someone

Comment: what if we need the revalidation too?